# Adding Specific cell in Body of Message

Tags: excel, vba

In my VBA, I need it to reference a specific cell in the body of the email.  When adding only the first one it works, but when I add the ---& Worksheets("Summary").Range("K1").Value--- to the other lines, it is not working.  Any suggestions?

```
Sub SendEmailandAttachFile()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String
    Dim MakeJPG As String

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    strbody = "Good Day Everyone," & "<br><br>" & _
        "Please find the daily case report for the end of business Friday." & "<br>" & "Please let me know if you have any questions." & "<br>" & _
        "<br><br>" & "1) Cases Added Yesterday- " & Worksheets("Cases Open Yesterday").Range("D2").Value & "<br>" & "2) Cases Closed Yesterday - " & Worksheets("Cases Closed Yesterday").Range("D2").Value & "<br>" & "3) Open - " & Worksheets("Summary").Range("C5").Value & "<br>" & "4) Focus cases over 30 days old - " & Worksheets("Summary").Range("K1").Value & "<br>" & "5) Oldest Case - " & Worksheets("All Open").Range("C5").Value & "<br><br>" & "CSATs Returned Yesterday - " & "<br><br><br>"

              
    MakeJPG = CopyRangeToJPG("Chart", "C1:O22")

    If MakeJPG = "" Then
        MsgBox "Something go wrong, we can't create the mail"
        With Application
            .EnableEvents = True
            .ScreenUpdating = True
        End With
        Exit Sub
    End If


    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .Display
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Winn Daily Report " & Date
        .Attachments.Add MakeJPG, 1, 0
        .HTMLBody = "<html><p>" & strbody & "</p><img src=""cid:NamePicture.jpg"" width=700 height=250></html>" & .HTMLBody
        .Attachments.Add Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

```
Function CopyRangeToJPG(NameWorksheet As String, RangeAddress As String) As String
    Dim PictureRange As Range

    With ActiveWorkbook
        On Error Resume Next
        .Worksheets(NameWorksheet).Activate
        Set PictureRange = .Worksheets(NameWorksheet).Range(RangeAddress)
        
        If PictureRange Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Sorry this is not a correct range"
            On Error GoTo 0
            Exit Function
        End If
        
        PictureRange.CopyPicture
        With .Worksheets(NameWorksheet).ChartObjects.Add(PictureRange.Left, PictureRange.Top, PictureRange.Width, PictureRange.Height)
            .Activate
            .Chart.Paste
            .Chart.Export Environ$("temp") & Application.PathSeparator & "NamePicture.jpg", "JPG"
        End With
        .Worksheets(NameWorksheet).ChartObjects(.Worksheets(NameWorksheet).ChartObjects.Count).Delete
    End With
    
    CopyRangeToJPG = Environ$("temp") & Application.PathSeparator & "NamePicture.jpg"
    Set PictureRange = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: `it is not working.` What do you mean by not working? Are you getting an error message? Not the expected output? What exactly is not working?

Answer (score 1):

Refactor the code to make it easier to identify the problem.

```vb
  Dim strbody, ar(5)
  ar(1) = Worksheets("Cases Open Yesterday").Range("D2").Value
  ar(2) = Worksheets("Cases Closed Yesterday").Range("D2").Value
  ar(3) = Worksheets("Summary").Range("C5").Value
  ar(4) = Worksheets("Summary").Range("K1").Value
  ar(5) = Worksheets("All Open").Range("C5").Value

  strbody = "Good Day Everyone,<br><br>" & _
        "Please find the daily case report for the end of business Friday.<br>" & _
        "Please let me know if you have any questions.<br><br>" & _
        "<br>1) Cases Added Yesterday- " & ar(1) & _
        "<br>2) Cases Closed Yesterday - " & ar(2) & _
        "<br>3) Open - " & ar(3) & _
        "<br>4) Focus cases over 30 days old - " & ar(4) & _
        "<br>5) Oldest Case - " & ar(5) & _
        "<br><br>CSATs Returned Yesterday - <br><br><br>"
  Debug.Print Join(Split(strbody, "<br>"), vbCrLf)
```

Comment: Thank you.  This part is now fixed.  Is there anyway to make the vba automatically add the prior weekday where "Friday" is showing so I do not have to change that in the email manually?             strbody = "Good Day Everyone," & "<br><br>" & _
        "Please find the daily case report for the end of business Friday.